# Display contents of object even if object is of type list

Tags: vb.net, list, object, complextype

What im trying to do is output to the console any complex object e.g.

pseudo object:

```
Orderheader:
customer = ""
OrderDate = ""
requiredDate = ""
contact = ""
customerOrderNumber = ""
deliverySubcode = ""
customerName = ""
customerAddress1 = ""
customerAddress2 = ""
customerAddress3 = ""
customerAddress4 = ""
List(Of Orderlines)

Orderline:
lineNumber = ""
productCode = ""
productDescription = ""
quantity = ""
unitPrice = ""
manufacturerProductCode = ""
weight = ""
```

so basicly go through each property in the orderHeader when it gets to the list of orderLines then enumerate through these and out put these to the console also, i want to be able to use this for anytype of object not just the object above the code i have at the moment is:

```
    Public Shared Sub ToFileNew(ByVal orderHeader As Object)

    Dim properties = orderHeader.GetType().GetProperties()
    For Each prop In properties
        If IsGenericList(prop.GetValue(orderHeader, New Object() {}).GetType) Then

            Dim subObjectList = prop.GetValue(orderHeader, New Object() {})
            Dim subPropertys = subObjectList.GetType().GetProperties()

            For Each x In subPropertys
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Name, x.GetValue(subObjectList, New Object() {}))
            Next

        Else
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(orderHeader, New Object() {}))
        End If

    Next

End Sub

Public Shared Function IsGenericList(type As Type) As Boolean
    If Not type Is Nothing Then
        Return (From [interface] In type.GetInterfaces() Where [interface].IsGenericType).Any(Function([interface]) [interface].GetGenericTypeDefinition() = GetType(ICollection(Of )))
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

the code works for the orderHeader but when gets to the list of Orderline I get the following error:

```
TargetParameterCountException was unhandled
Parameter count mismatch.
```

The purpose of this function will eventually write any object to CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone that has the same problem solution below:

```
    Public Shared Sub ToFileNew(ByVal orderHeader As Object)
    Dim properties = orderHeader.GetType().GetProperties()
    For Each prop In properties
        If IsGenericList(prop.GetValue(orderHeader, New Object() {}).GetType) Then
            Dim subObjectList = prop.GetValue(orderHeader)
            For Each p In subObjectList
                Dim subPropertys = p.GetType().GetProperties()
                For Each x In subPropertys
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Name, x.GetValue(p, New Object() {}))
                Next
            Next
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(orderHeader, New Object() {}))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Function IsGenericList(type As Type) As Boolean
    If Not type Is Nothing Then
        Return (From [interface] In type.GetInterfaces() Where [interface].IsGenericType).Any(Function([interface]) [interface].GetGenericTypeDefinition() = GetType(ICollection(Of )))
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```